# Count keys from nested array of objects

Tags: reactjs

There are an array that's length 4.this length always dynamic. 'attendance' is one of the key of this array of objects.this 'attendance' is also a array of object.

Now my query is: how to count (total) 'Make' key from 'attendance' array  when 'Make' value is '1'.

Array structure image is here:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVFQj.png]

Plz, help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you wanting a count of from the array(s)? What have you tried on your own? What isn't working? Do you want a total count from all elements, or an array of total counts for each attendance array? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I want to count 'Make' key for this array (which is length 4)  which is located on 'attendance' , when 'Make' value is '1'.

Comment: Do you have sample data you work from? And to clarify, you want a single total count from all the nested arrays?

Comment: Drew Reese, your answer is worked for me. I do appreciate your help. Many many thanks again and take love ❤️❤️, bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given data:

```
[
  {
    attendance: [
      { Make: "1", Model: "0", Year: "0", Present: "present" },
      { Make: "2", Model: "1", Year: "1", Absent: "absent" }
    ],
    "course-name": "OS",
    id: 61
  },
  {
    attendance: [
      { Make: "1", Model: "0", Year: "0", Absent: "absent" },
      { Make: "2", Model: "1", Year: "1", Present: "present" }
    ],
    "course-name": "OS",
    id: 62
  },
  {
    attendance: [
      { Make: "1", Model: "0", Year: "0" },
      { Make: "2", Model: "1", Year: "1" }
    ],
    "course-name": "",
    id: 63
  },
  {
    attendance: [
      { Make: "1", Model: "0", Year: "0" },
      { Make: "2", Model: "1", Year: "1" }
    ],
    "course-name": "",
    id: 64
  }
];
```

You can reduce the array into a total count, checking that each element's `attendance` array contains ***some*** element with a `Make` property equal to `"1"`.

```
data.reduce(
  (total, current) => total + current.attendance.some((el) => el.Make === "1"),
  0
);
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    attendance: [
      { Make: "1", Model: "0", Year: "0", Present: "present" },
      { Make: "2", Model: "1", Year: "1", Absent: "absent" }
    ],
    "course-name": "OS",
    id: 61
  },
  {
    attendance: [
      { Make: "1", Model: "0", Year: "0", Absent: "absent" },
      { Make: "2", Model: "1", Year: "1", Present: "present" }
    ],
    "course-name": "OS",
    id: 62
  },
  {
    attendance: [
      { Make: "1", Model: "0", Year: "0" },
      { Make: "2", Model: "1", Year: "1" }
    ],
    "course-name": "",
    id: 63
  },
  {
    attendance: [
      { Make: "1", Model: "0", Year: "0" },
      { Make: "2", Model: "1", Year: "1" }
    ],
    "course-name": "",
    id: 64
  }
];

const make1Count = data.reduce(
  (total, current) => total + current.attendance.some((el) => el.Make === "1"),
  0
);

console.log(make1Count);
```